# How do I run a local fish script on a remote server?

Tags: ssh, fish, remote-execution

With ssh and bash, it is possible to run a local bash script on a remote server:

```
$ ssh user@server "bash -s" -- < ./example.bash "--arg1" "arg2"
```

(from [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87405))

Assuming fish is installed on the remote server, what is the equivalent command to run a local fish script on a remote server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent command would be:

```
$ ssh user@host fish -- < ./example.fish --arg1 arg2
```

To demonstrate this locally (without ssh, and assuming the system has the */dev/stdin* device):

```
$ echo 'set -S argv' | fish -- /dev/stdin --abc def
$argv: not set in local scope
$argv: set in global scope, unexported, with 2 elements
$argv[1]: length=5 value=|--abc|
$argv[2]: length=3 value=|def|
$argv: not set in universal scope
```

Alternatively use */dev/fd/0*.

Comment: Just like your example: `ssh user@host fish /dev/stdin -- --arg1 arg2 <./example.fish`. My example was just a simplification to show how the solution works and correctly populates `$argv` and runs the script read from stdin. Without the complication of ssh and any problems its use introduces (e.g., authentication failures).